# "Fields" not created with the sample polls apps mentioned in docs of django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django & am trying to create the polls app mentioned in the documentation section of django page. 
Followed exact steps mentioned & when the concerned code is executed, it says models are created but i don't see the field is added.
Django version - 2.2.5
Python version - 3.6.4

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

as per docs, i should also see "- Add field question to choice" which is missing

Expected:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Choice
    - Create model Question
    - Add field question to choice
```

Actual:

```
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
    - Create model Choice
```

Comment: That's just a mistake in the tutorial. You shouldn't see that line.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh okay. But i still went forward but it was failing with the sql migrations command. I will share the full stack in a while.